# Visa requirements for traveling to Germany as an Indian citizen/married to a German

Tags: usa, schengen, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, us-residents

I am a German citizen, my wife is an Indian national. We both live in the USA and are both permanent residents (green card holders) and are full-time employed.

What type of permission is needed for her to travel with me to Germany? Does she need a visa? If so which type (tourist, visiting family/friends, etc.).

More information: The purpose is visiting in-laws and tourism (vacation), the duration is two weeks.

Please note: This is different from the already answered "Non-EU spouse of an EU citizen - is visiting EU without needing a visa possible?" since neither one of us lives in the EU.

Comment: The type of visa probably depends on the purpose, and possibly on the duration, of the trip.  Can you add that information to your question?

Comment: She will need **some** kind of visa, but the marriage will be much more important than her employment status or the purpose of the visit.

Comment: I began writing up an answer to say that she can get a normal Schengen short-stay visa if you're going to be there for 90 days or less, but the implications for that in combination with EU freedom of movement laws get to be truly weird.  I have a feeling that *someone* in the German administration has thought of this, so the short-stay visa may not be an option after all.  It may be that the only way to get a reliable answer will be to ask at the German consulate.

Comment: Indeed, I find the two answers in the related question answer this one completely. DinUS, if they do not satisfy you, please let us know in what way they do not.

Comment: @CGCampbell this question is not at all a duplicate and none of the linked answers addresses this question. For a trip to one's own country of citizenship (in this case, by a German citizen to Germany), when one does not reside in the EU, the European Union freedom of movement regime *does not apply in the least.* As far as I noticed, none of the answers so much as mentions this in the general case, let alone with respect to Germany.

Comment: It seems like the following applies:

Comment: It seems like the following applies: "If you are not resident in the EU, she will require a EU visa (Schengen visa if you're a Schengen country citizen), but this (by law) must be free and granted essentially automatically, all you need to prove is that you are married."

So far, good. I am still wondering which type of visa she needs in this case...

Comment: The latest edit by DinUS  isn't really true. The question marked as a duplicate **also** is asking about a couple for whom neither reside in the EU. @phoog 's argument is that this is different as state of citizenship only is in question, not the entirey of the EU, so EU rules do not apply.

Comment: @DinUS it does not apply to you because you are German visiting Germany with your wife, so German national law applies, not EU regulations. For the analogous situation in the UK, search for *Surinder Singh,* a case that established that EU rules *can* apply for someone in their own country under certain conditions. You don't seem to meet those conditions, however.

Comment: How good is your German? I'm not a lawyer, but chapter 2 section 6 AufenthG seems to be inapplicable because you're not living in Germany yourself. That leaves a Schengen visa in accordance with §6.

Comment: Another thought: the Schengen rules specify that the spouse of a "person enjoying freedom of movement" also enjoys freedom of movement when traveling with or to join the EU spouse. This person can therefore can use the EU passport line at a Schengen border, even if the spouse does not hold an EU passport. But Germany can make different rules for Germans not exercising freedom of movement, just as they can with visas and residence permits. Like I said, it can get weird. Still, I imagine you can both go to the EU line in a German airport.

Answer (score 2):

Now that the question is reopened, I'll try to summarize the comments.

- The Indian spouse will need a Schengen visa or a [residence permit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufenthaltstitel).
- She would probably qualify for a German residence permit under German law if the German spouse was resident in Germany (which he isn't). She would also have to show basic fluency in the language.
- She would qualify for a [residence permit under EU rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_card_of_a_family_member_of_a_Union_citizen) if the German spouse was resident in any other EU country (which he isn't). With this permit they could travel to Germany.

After a bit of googling, I couldn't find a *tourist visa* for the purpose of *family reunification*, because those usually result in a much more permanent residence permission. And the EU rules are based on the concept of [freedom of movement for workers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_movement_for_workers_in_the_European_Union) in the EU.

phoogs suggestions may be the best one, ask the consulate and edit this answer.

Comment: To qualify for the German residence permit, she'd need to prove a certain degree of proficiency in German.

Comment: @phoog, that was in my second bullet point. However, there are exceptions.